# Techniques to prove that $\sum a(k) = o(n^2)$ when $a(n) = o(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

Suppose that $a(n) \geq 0$ and $a(n) = o(n)$, in the sense that $\lim_n a(n) / n = 0$. Are there well-known methods to show that $\sum_{k = 1}^n a(k) = o(n^2)$?

I think I've proven this using "low-level" arguments (see below), but it's too *particular* for my tastes. I would really like to see a high-powered tool like Abel summation or the Euler-Maclaurin formula at work, but I don't know where to start. (For example, I'd like to see a generalization that says $a(n) = o(n^\alpha)$ implies $\sum_{k = 1}^n a(k) = o(n^{\alpha + 1})$.)

---

For any $\epsilon > 0$, find $N$ such that $a(n) < \epsilon n$ for $n \geq N$. Then $$\sum_{k = 0}^n a(k) \leq \sum_{0 \leq k < N} a(k) + \epsilon \sum_{k = N}^n k = \sum_{0 \leq k < N} a(k) + \epsilon O(n^2).$$ Dividing by $n^2$ and letting $n \to \infty$ shows that $$\limsup_n n^{-2} \sum_{k = 0}^n a(k) \leq \epsilon'$$ where $\epsilon'$ is some constant multiple of $\epsilon$, which proves the claim.

Comment: This is so simple just from the definitions that it's hard to see why you want another method - you don't _need_ a "method" here, just look at how big things are and add em up.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My proof implicitly uses $\sum_{k = 1}^n k^\alpha = O(n^{\alpha + 1})$. I only know how to prove this when $\alpha$ is an integer, in which case we know the closed form. I'm asking for an application of a general result that will apply to broader situations.

Comment: It’s really overkill to try and use a high-powered tool for such a result. If anything, you should appreciate your elementary proof. About the sum of the $n^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 0$, consider $\int_{n-1}^n{x^{\alpha}\,dx} \leq n^{\alpha} \leq \int_n^{n+1}{x^{\alpha}\,dx}$.

Comment: Of course it's overkill, but sometimes overkill on easy problems demonstrates techniques with training wheels :)

Comment: You can also see that $0 \leq n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k} \leq n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k/k}$, and by Stolz-Cesaro the RHS goes to zero.